# Deadlock on filedialog in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm running Windows 7 64bit on my laptop - I hooked an external HD via usb3. When saving something in certain applications (notepad), the file dialog pops up then the whole system is freezing. Like applications won't react anymore, also taskmanager, so I can't terminate anything.

I think it's the external HD which is powering down after a while. Anyone who knows this problem and can tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Brand and model of external drive? Specific Model of Laptop? Some external drives had bundled software to install which allows you to change some of the settings for the external drive such as when it sleeps. Sounds like another issue to me though.

Comment: the hd is a samsung HD204UI (2 TB) .. gotta look that up.
i think i will disable poweroff ..

Comment: That is the model number of the hard drive, I assumed it was an retail external drive in an enclosure, how did you connect the drive using usb, an enclosure?

Comment: yes i connected it via usb-to-sata adapter from hama ..

Comment: probably an adapter issue, not all adapters are worth having, since it is an adapter and not an enclosure there will be no software to control sleep. Buy a higher quality adapter or hard drive enclosure.